# How do I merge data with CountVectorizer features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Here's my dataset

```
        body                                            customer_id   name
14828   Thank you to apply to us.                       5458          Sender A
23117   Congratulation your application is accepted.    5136          Sender B
23125   Your OTP will expire in 10 minutes.             5136          Sender A
```

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
b = a['body']
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(b)
X_vect=vect.transform(b)
pd.DataFrame(X_vect.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```

The output is

```
    10  application apply ... your  
0   0   0           1         0
1   0   1           0         1
2   1   0           0         1
```

What I need is

```
        body                                            customer_id   name        10  application apply ... your
14828   Thank you to apply to us.                       5458          Sender A    0   0           1         0
23117   Congratulation your application is accepted.    5136          Sender B    0   1           0         1
23125   Your OTP will expire in 10 minutes.             5136          Sender A    1   0           0         1
```

How suppose I do this? I'm still hoping to use `CountVectorizer` so I can modify the function in the future

Comment: Of course you won't have the rest o the data. You sliced at first only `a['body']` to your fit :) Have to merge back the initial info to recover that

Comment: noted, it is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `index` to `Dataframe` contructor and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df` with default `left join`:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(X_vect.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names(), index= a.index)
a = a.join(b)
```

Or use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but need more parameters, because default is `inner join`:

```
a = a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: So, merge is can't be used?

Comment: `join` is like `merge` with left join :)

Comment: Just info, you need to reset_index b first, but thanks, it works